# When inserting a new row in table A, another row also gets inserted in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, database-trigger

So I am working with these two tables, `Dependency` and `DependencyList`.

[image]
[image]

I am trying to write an SQL query that, when a new row gets created in table `Dependencies`, another one also gets created in `DependencyList`, having the `DependencyId` filled with the `Id` of the newly created Dependency.

The `Id` column of both tables is auto-incremented.

Would that be possible, in any way?

Comment: You can use trigger. But how about inserting explicitly into both

Comment: Yeah, but how do I know the auto-incremented `Id` of the newly created row from the `Dependencies` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically do this with a `FOR INSERT` trigger. You can access the previously generated `id` using the `inserted` pseudo-table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger ON Dependencies FOR INSERT
AS INSERT INTO DependencyList (DependencyId) SELECT Id FROM inserted;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bffac2776941fd93a2ec0b069c2982ea)**

You can also do this with two `insert` statements, using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to retrieve the last insert `id`:

```
INSERT INTO Dependencies(isResolved, AssignedToTaskId) VALUES(0, 0);
INSERT INTO DependencyList (DependencyId) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b16463e4796a4a82467bd35d2add0b0)**